# How to set a DynamoDB environment variable in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, environment-variables

I have a Golang which connects to a DynamoDB.

The name of the db table was hard-coded and now it is set to read from an environment variable using `os.LookupEnv()`.

I unit tested locally with the variable being read from a `secrets.env` file, but I wonder how to proceed to make it work when deployed in production?

I suppose that I need to set this on `AWS` config somehow?

Comment: Depends on the services you (want to) use. E.g. AWS lambda simply has an "environment variables" section.

Comment: It depends entirely on where you are running the code (EC2, ECS, EKS, Lambda, Elastic Beanstalk, etc.). Each service has a different way of setting up environment variables. If by "`AWS` config" you mean using the CLI tool `aws config` then no, you would not do that on AWS, you would use an IAM role. If you mean the AWS Config service, then no you wouldn't use that either, since that is a service for tracking your infrastructure configuration changes, not for storing API keys.

Answer (score 3):

No, you would not store it in `aws config` that is for configuring access keys, which I also recommend not doing, use an IAM role attached to whichever service you are using is best practice.

As for DynamoDB table name as an env variable, its totally up to how you wish to do it. You can store it as an env variable on the OS in EC2 for example. Or if using Lambda you can use its [Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html)

You can also use [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to store environments variables and is common practice.

Comment: How can I store it as an env variable on the OS in EC2? I only found tutorials for the Parameter Store; any link would be helpful